# How to handle null properties not used in MVC View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am using EF objects as model in views. Some of EF objects has lots of properties that I don't want to show them in view. So I am creating only needed properties' html controls. But while MVC controller mapping, EF writes not used properties as null on to actual values in table. How can I write only used properties (not null)? Or how can I map only not null properties over the current EF object?

Edit:
I think checking not null properties may be best practice for this problem. How can I do this mapping easily?

Comment: Are you asking how to update only properties that are used in view? Also can you post the code

Comment: Yes, I need to update only used ones. I have no code on this, just researching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void AutoMapping(MappingMod _MappingMod, object _Destination, object _Resource)
    {
        Type resourceType = _Resource.GetType();

        IList<PropertyInfo> props = resourceType.GetProperties();

        if (_MappingMod == MappingMod.AllPropertiesAndNotEnumerableProperties || _MappingMod == MappingMod.NotNullPropertiesAndNotEnumerableProperties)
        {
            props = props.Where(m => m.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual != true).ToList();
        }

        Type destinationType = _Destination.GetType();

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
        {
            PropertyInfo destinationProp = destinationType.GetProperty(prop.Name);

            if (destinationProp != null)
            {
                if (AutoMappingController(_MappingMod, _Destination, _Resource, prop))
                {
                    destinationProp.SetValue(_Destination, prop.GetValue(_Resource, null));
                }
            }
        }
    }


public enum MappingMod
{
AllProperties,
NotNullProperties,
AllPropertiesAndNotEnumerableProperties,
NotNullPropertiesAndNotEnumerableProperties
}
```

Comment: Please don't just give a code dump without explaining what we're looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You could either manually or via a tool like AutoMapper, map your domain/EF model to a ViewModel which is then what you stringly type your Views to. During this mapping you can perform the necessary checks on property values to prepare them for display in your View. You could also create read-only properties in your ViewModel that do null checks and expose the value if present or an empty string if required for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have separate ViewModel classes (act as a wrapper around your actual EF generated class) that only contain the properties you want.

Or Can hide a property from the view using `Data Annotations`. In order to accomplish this, you should  decorate the property which you wanted to hide with following annotation.

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
```

Second option seems to be quick and ideal in your case.

Comment: I am not using Code First. And some of props may be used on another view. So changing model is not a solution for me.

Comment: Seperate models needs to be written for each one. That is a waste of time.

Comment: In that case, the only option you leftover is to have a middle man ( viewmodel) for each view. And this individual view model can customize the properties.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this.

```
public ActionResult UpdateTable(Table t)
{
    var up = _dbContext.Table.Find(t.ID);  //t.ID is  Primary Key
    up.Name = t.Name;
    // All the fields you need to update
    _dbContext.Entry(Table).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
     return View(up);

}
```

Also you can you can create hidden field for a property like this

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)
```

Comment: Hidden fiels may be modified by user. I don't want to use hiddens.

Comment: @Baran You can only update the fields you want in EF. See the first snippet.

Comment: // All the fields you need to update
This job must be done by hand. It must be auto.